# Multiple Bipartite graphs and matchings

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, probability-distributions, random-graphs

I've been told recently that it's better i just for help regarding my 'specific' problem rather than lots of little questions around the same topic which appear somewhat unclear. I would first like to apologize for this, my initial intentions were to not ask my specific problem but rather obtain relevant hints to solve it myself through other little related questions. Clearly i have taken the wrong approach and have ended up asking lots of little useless questions and have not really got any closer to solving it as a result, but i am glad to have learnt a valuable lesson. So here goes,

I know how to construct a proof to find the threshold value for a perfect matching in a random bipartite graph. My problem is slightly more involved. Suppose i have $f(n)$ random bipartite graphs each independent with vertex classes of size $\omega(n)$, here typically $\omega(n)$ would be a function between $\mathrm{log}(n)$ and $n$ in size (i realise this huge) and $f(n)$ is typically quadratic in $n$. I have the following

1. I want to obtain an estimate of the largest matching in a single on of these bipartite graphs, clearly above the threshold value i know i have a perfect matching but what could i say about values of $p$ much lower than this threshold?
2. I want to combine this result on all $f(n)$ bipartite graphs for different values of $p$, i.e a result which shows w.h.p i can expect each one to have a matching of some size perhaps within an interval. Perhaps even a range for $p$ for which i could expect to have a perfect matching in all of them w.h.p (the problem being i don't know the error probability of not having a matching in a bipartite graph).

I'm not sure what computational tools would be useful for this specific problem, so far i'm looking at martingales with the idea that i could obtain a bound on the probability that the largest matching deviates from the expectation by some size in any one of the $f(n)$ bipartite graphs and then perhaps use a union bound to show that the probability at least one of the matchings is of a size outside this interval $\rightarrow 0$ maybe through chernoff bounds or something? I would really appreciate any help with regards to what kind of tools i could look into for this problem. Are martingales the right approach to take or is there something better i could use. I hope this puts a lot of my previous questions into context, thanks!